# RuntimeError when re-instantiating a TensorFlow Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've got a model that I've built using a TensorFlow `DNNClassifier` Estimator model.

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=get_feature_columns(),
    hidden_units=[128, 128],
    model_dir="/tmp/logs",
    n_classes=n_classes,
    dropout=0.3,
    optimizer=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
    config=run_config,
)
```

This instantiation works just fine when I run it in a notebook initially, but whenever I want to go back and change something by running the cell again and re-instantiating the model, I get a RuntimeError:

```
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

This seems strange because it should be creating a new graph from scratch, not modifying an existing one. Any idea why this would happen?

Running TF 2.4.1 on Python 3.7

Comment: `NameError: name 'get_feature_columns' is not defined` is what I get when I run your code. Please make your error reproducible.

Comment: I guess I'm just looking for information about how Estimators work in general. Irrespective of the specifics of a particular model, why would instantiating a second model fail just because a previous model was instantiated? I'm wondering if there is a side effect kicking around somewhere that I'm not aware of.